# Which version of Apache should I choose?

Tags: php, windows, apache

There are 6 choices for me now to run PHP5.3(VC9) or PHP5.2(VC6)

```
PHP5.3(VC9)
 Apache2.2+Windows2008 32Bit
 Apache2.2+Windows2008 64Bit

 Apache2.4+Windows2008 32Bit
 Apache2.4 +Windows2008 64Bit

PHP5.2(VC6)
 Apache2.2+Windows2003
 Apache2.4+Windows2003
```

Which combination is best choice, and why, or another choice?
Are there any good points to choice, like stability, compatibility and life cycle?

Answer (score 2):

You should run PHP5.3(VC9) with Windows2008 64Bit and Apache2.4

It will get you the best performance and uses the latest updates with the most ability for memory upgrades.

Comment: I understand this recommendation newest is the best. Now I need some information about stability of this combination. Dose anyone know?

Comment: it is about as stable as it gets. you can use linux alternatively, but as long as you don't use more RAM than you have available, it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: It is my comprehension that unless my application is written well managing memory usage, apache or PHP will stop. Maybe this opinion is not only for newest combination but also other combination. Do I misunderstand ?